# Getting domain part from path

Tags: php

If I use `__DIV__` I get path something like this:

```
/home/domaincom/public_html/account/assets
```

I need to get the **domaincom** part only, how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Replace everything else?

Comment: explode on `/` perhaps

Comment: Did you mean `__DIR__`? Are you asking how to get the home directory of the script owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, there's actually no 'easy' way to get this with [**`$_SERVER`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) alone.

Instead, first retrieve the path with `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` and use **[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** on the `/`:

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
//$url = "/home/domaincom/public_html/account/assets";
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$domain = $parts[2];
echo $domain; // domaincom
```

I've created a working example showcasing this **[here](https://3v4l.org/hNbRB)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Why use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`? OP seems to have the directory they want to parse already and there's nothing in this question indicating the script is executed by an HTTP server

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns a physical file system path; it can be used under any protocol, not just HTTP.

Comment: Oh really? Try running your script via the CLI. Also, I'm not talking about protocols, I mean HTTP server, eg Apache, nginx, IIS, etc. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is only ever populated when PHP is executed by a web server